# Jodatime IllegalInstantException

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime, android-jodatime

I've tried almost everything about this snippet, and I still get IllegalInstentException.

```
public int getDateDay() {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTime dt;
    try {
        dt = formatter.parseDateTime(date);
    } catch (IllegalInstantException e) {
        dt = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(date).toDateTime();
    }
    return dt.getDayOfMonth();
}
```

> Fatal Exception: org.joda.time.IllegalInstantException Illegal instant
>   due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'):
>   2018-10-21T00:00:00.000 (America/Sao_Paulo) keyboard_arrow_up
>   arrow_right org.joda.time.chrono.ZonedChronology.localToUTC
>   (ZonedChronology.java:157)
>   org.joda.time.chrono.ZonedChronology.getDateTimeMillis
>   (ZonedChronology.java:122)
>   org.joda.time.chrono.AssembledChronology.getDateTimeMillis
>   (AssembledChronology.java:133) org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.
>   (BaseDateTime.java:257) org.joda.time.DateTime. (DateTime.java:532)
>   org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.toDateTime (LocalDateTime.java:750)
>   org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.toDateTime (LocalDateTime.java:731)

Comment: What is `date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the input is not a valid date. The problem has been discussed in this [page](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/470).

Reason:

> Joda-Time only allows the key classes to store valid date-times. For
>   example, 31st February is not a valid date so it can't be stored
>   (except in Partial).
>
> The same principle of valid date-times applies to daylight savings
>   time (DST). In many places DST is used, where the local clock moves
>   forward by an hour in spring and back by an hour in autumn/fall. This
>   means that in spring, there is a "gap" where a local time does not
>   exist.
>
> The error "Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition" refers
>   to this gap. **It means that your application tried to create a
>   date-time inside the gap - a time that did not exist.** Since Joda-Time
>   objects must be valid, this is not allowed.

Possible solutions may be as follows:

> - Use LocalDateTime, as all local date-times are valid.
> - When converting a LocalDate to a DateTime, then use toDateTimeAsStartOfDay()  as this handles and manages any gaps.
> - When parsing, use parseLocalDateTime() if the string being parsed has no time-zone.